# Save images at runtime in iphone app

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Which one is better at runtime:
1)saving images of size 250X120 in sqlite.
2)Saving images of same size in document directory.
At two three places app needs these saved images to be shown in the control.
Also i am having requirement to show maximum of 20 images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is far better than first one. To accomplish second part use:

```
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image:(NSString*)imageName
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); //convert image into .png format.

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory

    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageName]]; //add our image to the path 

    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (image)

    NSLog(@"image saved");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 M.Sharjeel - and what we use is usually a semi-hybrid, where we'll have a Core Data object (backed by sqlite on the phone/pad) which has metadata about the file that is fast to search, then store a NSString to the path within the documentsDirectory.

Comment: Agree with him.. Core data is efficient and performs better than SqlIte

Answer (score 0):

If you take the documents directory approach, this is a good way to accomplish it.

```
-(void) saveImage:(UIImage *)image withFileName:(NSString *)imageName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else {
        ALog(@"Image Save Failed\nExtension: (%@) is not recognized, use (PNG/JPG)", extension);
    }
}
```

To save an image, simply do it like this:

```
NSString * path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
[self saveImage:yourImage withFileName:@"Your Image Name" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:path];
```

To load the image, implement this method:

```
-(UIImage *) loadImage:(NSString *)fileName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {

    UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", directoryPath, fileName, extension]];

    return result;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
NSString * path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
yourImage.image = [self loadImage:@"Your Image Name" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:path];
```

Or you could simply set your image equal to what this method returns instead of creating a method:

```
NSString * path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
yourImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Your Image Name.png", path]];
```